# tensorflow mask boxes with selected indices

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

Suppose I have a rank-2 tensor **A** `[[1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3], [4, 4, 4, 4], ...]`, and I have a selected indices **B** (from `tf.equal()` or somewhere else) such as `[1, 3, 4]` . I want to make **A[i]** all zero for any **i** in **B** so that **A** eventually becomes something like `[1,1,1,1], [0,0,0,0],[3,3,3,3], [0,0,0,0], ...]`. How to do that or is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that. Here's one with [`tf.one_hot()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot) (tested code):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant( [[1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3], [4, 4, 4, 4]] )
b = tf.constant( [ 1, 3, 4 ] )

one_hot = tf.one_hot( b, a.get_shape()[ 0 ].value, dtype = a.dtype )
mask = 1 - tf.reduce_sum( one_hot, axis = 0 )
res = a * mask[ ..., None ]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print( sess.run( res ) )
```

or this one with [`tf.scatter_nd()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd) (tested code):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant( [[1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3], [4, 4, 4, 4]] )
b = tf.constant( [ 1, 3 ] )

mask = 1 - tf.scatter_nd( b[ ..., None ], tf.ones_like( b ), shape = [ a.get_shape()[ 0 ].value ] )
res = a * mask[ ..., None ]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print( sess.run( res ) )
```

will both output:

> [[1 1 1 1]
>    [0 0 0 0]
>    [3 3 3 3]
>    [0 0 0 0]]

as desired.