# tensorflow remember the index after calculating getting the maximum box

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

Assume that I have two arrays of boxes, each of which has the shape `(?, b1, 4)` and `(?, b2, 4)` respectively (treat `?` as a unknown batch size):

```
box1: [[[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6]...]...]
box2: [[[4,3,2,1], [3,2,5,4], [4,3,5,6]...]...]
```

(the number above are set arbitarily)

I want to:

1. in each batch, for each box **A** in `box1`, find in `box2` the box **B** which has the maximum IOU (intersection over union) with **A** (in the same batch, of course), and then append the tuple **(A, B)** to a list **list_max**.
2. append to **list_nonmax** all the boxes in `box2` that does not have maximum IOU with any box in `box1` (separated by batch, of course)

You can assume that:

1. **b1** and **b2** are both python variables, not tensorflow tensor.
2. methods for calculating IOU between single box or between batch of boxes already exists and can be used literally:

   `iou_single_box(box1, box2)` : both *box1* and *box2* are of shape `(4,)`.

   `iou_multiple_boxes(bbox1, bbox2)` : both *bbox1* and *bbox2* are of shape `(b1, 4)` and `(b2, 4)` respectively.

   `iou_batch_boxes(bbbox1, bbbox2)` : both *bbbox1* and *bbbox2* are of shape `(?, b1, 4)` and `(?, b2, 4)` respectively (treat `?` as a unknown batch size).

I found these particularly hard in tensorflow, especially for the **list_nonmax** case, because, whereas it is easy to use padding and then `tf.reduce_max()` to get box tuples with maximum iou, it is impossible to remember their index and then extract out boxes for **list_nonmax**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`tf.nn.top_k()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/top_k) for this. It returns both the maximum value *and* the index it's at at the last dimension.

```
val, idx = tf.nn.top_k( iou_batch_boxes( bbbox1, bbbox2 ), k = 1 )
```

will give you the `box2` index with the max iou for each `box1` and batch.

To get your ***list_max*** you need to [`tf.stack()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) `box1` with `box2`'s entries by `idx` with [`tf.gather_nd()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) along axis ***1***. Here's a working code with a dummy iou function:

```
import tensorflow as tf

box1 = tf.reshape( tf.constant( range( 16 ), dtype = tf.float32 ), ( 2, 2, 4 ) )
box2 = tf.reshape( tf.constant( range( 2, 26 ), dtype = tf.float32 ), ( 2, 3, 4 ) )
batch_size = box1.get_shape().as_list()[ 0 ]

def dummy_iou_batch_boxes( box1, box2 ):
    b1s, b2s = box1.get_shape().as_list(), box2.get_shape().as_list()
    return tf.constant( [ [ [9.0,8,7], [1,2,3],
                            [0  ,1,2], [0,5,0] ] ] )

iou = dummy_iou_batch_boxes( box1, box2 )
val, idx = tf.nn.top_k( iou, k = 1 )
idx = tf.reshape( idx, ( batch_size, box1.get_shape().as_list()[ 1 ] ) )
one_hot_idx = tf.one_hot( idx, depth = box2.get_shape().as_list()[ 1 ] )
full_idx = tf.where( tf.equal( 1.0, one_hot_idx ) )
box1_idx = full_idx[ :, 0 : 2 ]
box2_idx = full_idx[ :, 0 : 3 : 2 ]
box12 = tf.gather_nd( box1, box1_idx )
box22 = tf.gather_nd( box2, box2_idx )
list_max = tf.stack( [ box12, box22 ], axis = 1 )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run( [ list_max ] )
    for v in res:
        print( v )
        print( "-----------------------------")
```

will output:

> [[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
>     [ 2.  3.  4.  5.]]
>
> [[ 4.  5.  6.  7.]
>     [10. 11. 12. 13.]]
>
> [[ 8.  9. 10. 11.]
>     [22. 23. 24. 25.]]
>
> [[12. 13. 14. 15.]
>     [18. 19. 20. 21.]]]

If you want this as a list or tuple, you can use [`tf.unstack()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unstack) on the above `list_max`.

To get ***list_nonmax*** the thing you need is merging the indices into a mask, which I believe I've already answered in [another one of your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50195282/tensorflow-mask-boxes-with-selected-indices), but the important part is:

```
mask = tf.reduce_max( tf.one_hot( idx, depth = num_bbbox2 ), axis = -2 )
```

This will give you a mask with shape ***( batch, num_box2 )*** telling you for each batch and each of `box2` if that `box2` is the max iou one for *any* `box1`.

From here, you can either use the mask or get the list of indices with [`tf.where()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) like this:

```
was_never_max_idx = tf.where( tf.equal( 0, mask ) )
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the `tf.nn.top_k()`! But how can I get `list_max` so that I can operate on that?

Comment: Sure, happy to help. Updated answer. By the way, if you have some time, can you please accept the answers on your previous questions? You know, to motivate people to answer... :) You have a lot of unaccepted answers: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4845608/walkerlala?tab=questions&sort=newest

Comment: Sorry for that. But, `tf.gather()` cannot operate on batch level. Suppose `box2` is `(2, 5, 4)` and indices is `(2, 3, 1)` (where `2` is the batch size), the result of `tf.gather` will be `(2, 2, 3, 1 ,4)` instead of `(2, 3, 1, 4)`

Comment: Okay, so you need to get the diagonal, so for batch 0 you take [ 0, 0, ... ] and batch 1 you take [ 1, 1, ... ] etc. Alternatively, use `tf.gather_nd()` that gives you more granular control, but you have to assemble the indices.

Comment: what do you mean by *get the diagonal*. With `tf.one_hot`?  Can that help in this situation for tf.gather?

Comment: No, not that. So basically the tensor you get with the above will pack all batches' `box1` with all batches` max `box2`. You only need the diagonal of that matrix, the pairs from the same batch. Try `tf.diag_part()` if that's useful, albeit not sure if that's going to mess up the internal dimensions as well.

Comment: So the problem now reduces to: given a result of shape `(2, 2, 3, 1 ,4)`, how to get `[0,0]` and `[1, 1]` and discard `[0, 1]` and `[1,0]`. `tf.diag_part ` cannot handle this because it requires equal dimension (you cannot specify the axis in it)

Comment: Ok updated my answer with actual code with a dummy iou function

Comment: :) Thanks. Was too lazy to do 0 and 2 and concat. ;)

Comment: Hi, there is a new (harder) question built on top of this. Would to like to take a challenge?

Comment: Sure why not. Post the link. I have meetings in the next several hours but can take a look after that.

Comment: Ah I forgot the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50561871/tensorflow-get-boxes-pair-with-maximum-iou-but-discard-boxes-with-all-zeros