# tensorflow get boxes pair with maximum IOU but discard boxes with all zeros

Tags: tensorflow

This question is built from this question: ([tensorflow remember the index after calculating getting the maximum box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50214219/tensorflow-remember-the-index-after-calculating-getting-the-maximum-box)). I find discarding boxes with all zeros particularly hard, so I am posting a new one.

Complete description:

---

Assume that I have two arrays of boxes, each of which has the shape `(?, b1, 4)` and `(?, b2, 4)` respectively (treat `?` as a unknown batch size):

```
box1: [[[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]...]...]
box2: [[[4,3,2,1], [3,2,5,4], [4,3,5,6]...]...]
```

(the number above are set arbitarily)

Note that `box1` **may or may not** have *fake box*(`[0,0,0,0]`) at the end.

I want to:

1. in each batch, for each *non-fake* box **A** in `box1` (that is, boxes that does not contain all zeros), find in `box2` the box **B** which has the maximum IOU (intersection over union) with **A** (in the same batch, of course), and then append the tuple **(A, B)** to a list **list_max**.
2. append to **list_nonmax** all the boxes in `box2` that does not have maximum IOU with any box in `box1` (separated by batch, of course)

You can assume that:

1. **b1** and **b2** are both python variables, not tensorflow tensor.
2. methods for calculating IOU between single box or between batch of boxes already exists and can be used literally:

   `iou_single_box(box1, box2)` : both *box1* and *box2* are of shape `(4,)`.

   `iou_multiple_boxes(bbox1, bbox2)` : both *bbox1* and *bbox2* are of shape `(b1, 4)` and `(b2, 4)` respectively.

   `iou_batch_boxes(bbbox1, bbbox2)` : both *bbbox1* and *bbbox2* are of shape `(?, b1, 4)` and `(?, b2, 4)` respectively (treat `?` as a unknown batch size).

---

You can take a look at the question  ([tensorflow remember the index after calculating getting the maximum box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50214219/tensorflow-remember-the-index-after-calculating-getting-the-maximum-box)) I post previously. I only add one constraint:

1. I don't want any *fake* box in `box1` to match against any box in `box2`. when getting **list_max** and **list_nonmax**

Note that the number of fake box is not set.

****: I know this question is quite complicated. I do all these because Tensorflow cannot handle dynamic-length array (you have to have a deterministic `b1` for `box1` at runtime). So I pad `[0, 0, 0, 0]` at the end of `box1` to make the length fixed.

Comment: Since the previous question is still unanswered, please prefer _editing_ that one to include that constraint, instead of asking another question. Moreover, while you're at it, consider showing your research effort and presenting your own attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: @E_net4 The previous answer is answered (20 days ago). And I have done tons of effort to solve that problem (using lots of for/while loop), which I don't think is appropriate to show here (will make the question more complicated). The reason I clearly state the problem is not that I am lazy, it is because I think it will make people more clear about what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is easily doable with [`tf.boolean_mask()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask) like this code (tested):

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf

box1 = tf.reshape( tf.constant( range( 16 ), dtype = tf.float32 ), ( 2, 2, 4 ) )
box1 = tf.concat( [ box1, tf.zeros( ( 2, 2, 4 ) ) ], axis = 1 )
box2 = tf.reshape( tf.constant( range( 2, 26 ), dtype = tf.float32 ), ( 2, 3, 4 ) )
batch_size = box1.get_shape().as_list()[ 0 ]

def dummy_iou_batch_boxes( box1, box2 ):
    b1s, b2s = box1.get_shape().as_list(), box2.get_shape().as_list()
    return tf.constant( [ [ [9.0,8,7], [1,2,3], [ 0, 10, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ],
                            [0  ,1,2], [0,5,0], [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ] ] ] )

iou = dummy_iou_batch_boxes( box1, box2 )
val, idx = tf.nn.top_k( iou, k = 1 )
idx = tf.reshape( idx, ( batch_size, box1.get_shape().as_list()[ 1 ] ) )
one_hot_idx = tf.one_hot( idx, depth = box2.get_shape().as_list()[ 1 ] )

# for listmax
full_idx = tf.where( tf.equal( 1.0, one_hot_idx ) )
box1_idx = full_idx[ :, 0 : 2 ]
box2_idx = full_idx[ :, 0 : 3 : 2 ]
box12 = tf.gather_nd( box1, box1_idx )
box22 = tf.gather_nd( box2, box2_idx )
list_max_raw = tf.stack( [ box12, box22 ], axis = 1 )
# filter out for a = [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
nonzero_mask = tf.reduce_any( tf.not_equal( 0.0, list_max_raw ), axis = 2 )[ :, 0 ]
list_max = tf.boolean_mask( list_max_raw, nonzero_mask )

# for list nonmax
nonzero_mask = tf.cast( tf.reduce_any( tf.not_equal( 0.0, box1 ), axis = 2 ), tf.float32 )[ ..., None ]
filtered_one_hot = one_hot_idx * nonzero_mask
active_box2 = tf.sign( tf.reduce_sum( filtered_one_hot, axis = 1 ) )
nonactive_box2 = 1.0 - active_box2
nonactive_box2_idx = tf.where( tf.equal( 1.0, nonactive_box2 ) )
list_nonmax = tf.gather_nd( box2, nonactive_box2_idx )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run( [ box1, box2, list_max ] )
    print( "Input boxes:  " )
    for v in res[ : 2 ]:
        print( v )
        print( " ", "=" * 40 )
    print( "List max:  " )
    for v in res[ 2 : ]:
        print( v )
        print( " ", "=" * 40 )
    res = sess.run( [ list_nonmax ] )
    print( "List nonmax:  " )
    for v in res:
        print( v )
        print( " ", "=" * 40 )
```

will output

> Input boxes:
>   [[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
>     [ 4.  5.  6.  7.]
>     [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
>     [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]
>
> [[ 8.  9. 10. 11.]
>     [12. 13. 14. 15.]
>     [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
>     [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]]
>     ========================================
>   [[[ 2.  3.  4.  5.]
>     [ 6.  7.  8.  9.]
>     [10. 11. 12. 13.]]
>
> [[14. 15. 16. 17.]
>     [18. 19. 20. 21.]
>     [22. 23. 24. 25.]]]
>     ========================================
>   List max:
>   [[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
>     [ 2.  3.  4.  5.]]
>
> [[ 4.  5.  6.  7.]
>     [10. 11. 12. 13.]]
>
> [[ 8.  9. 10. 11.]
>     [22. 23. 24. 25.]]
>
> [[12. 13. 14. 15.]
>     [18. 19. 20. 21.]]]
>     ========================================
>   List nonmax:
>   [[ 6.  7.  8.  9.]
>    [14. 15. 16. 17.]]
>     ========================================

Comment: Yes the real hard part is `list_nonmax`, because *fake* boxes might "consume" some boxes. Any idea for that now?

Comment: Ok will take a look at it later. You just have to mask the mask... :)

Comment: I am trying on it. But I am having problem "cross-reference" the two lists. Sometimes those fake boxes will "consume" some boxes and sometimes will not, so to find out whether that is the case you have kind of check it against `list_max`, which is difficult without **if/else** expression...

Comment: Problem is I'm doing actual work now so cannot spend time on this. Will try to do late night or tomorrow. The idea is to mask the one-hot tensors with the mask of zeros, so the index list `one_hot_idx` wouldn't have those, and then you can just select the rest. Not sure if this makes sense? Will try to code this for you when I have some time.